# How do I make a Canvas in Android?

Tags: android, canvas

I don't understand how to make a canvas in android. I've looked at a lot of tutorials, and I think I followed them correctly, but I clearly didn't as it still doesn't work. Here is the code I have for my main activity:

```
package com.example.dan.shootyguy;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void neato(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DrawThing.class);
    }
}
```

I think this part works, but it isn't changing how the app looks so I can't be sure.

Then, I have another class where I have the canvas and onDraw:

```
package com.example.dan.shootyguy;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawThing extends View{

    Paint paint = new Paint(Color.RED);

    public DrawThing(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawOval(25f,25f,25f,25f,paint);
    }

}
```

This should be making a red circle, but it doesn't do anything. Can anyone offer any help? Thanks.

Comment: Your function `neato` is not called and if it was it wouldn't do anything. Also you probably don't want intents, you want to add your canvas to the layout.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't explain that part. Neato is the onClick for the button I have in my XML file. Also, how do I add the canvas to the layout? I've never done stuff with canvases before.

Comment: @moxide You can add it to your Canvas after drawing with the addView method.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Android, can you explain how I'd do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View(DrawThing ) con't call by intent 
Try this...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         DrawThing draw=new DrawThing(this);
            setContentView(draw);

        }


    }
```

Comment: The app crashes when I have this in it, so I don't know.

Comment: Oh, I retried it and it works now, I don't know what I was doing wrong before. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the onDraw method is fine you just didn't tell it to draw anything.

> drawOval
>
> void drawOval (float left, 
>                   float top, 
>                   float right, 
>                   float bottom, 
>                   Paint paint) Draw the specified oval using the specified paint. The oval will be filled or framed based on the Style
>   in the paint.

You told it canvas.drawOval(25f,25f,25f,25f,paint); that's an oval bounded by 25,25,25,25 it's 0 wide and 0 high. In other words, just kick it out and don't draw anything. Maybe a pixel but, that's even doubtful.

You can very much override the draw routine and draw stuff. You just have to tell it something that exists to draw.